# Cannot clone repository with eGit

Tags: eclipse, git, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, egit

I'm trying to clone a repo for a project for university. Here are the details:

```
Eclipse 3.7.2.v20120207-1839

STS 2.9.2.201205071000-RELEASE

EGit    1.3.0.201202151440-r

GNU/Linux Debian 3.0.0-1-amd64 x86_64
```

First I try to import the project: Import > Projects from Git > URI >

URI: `https://USERNAME@HOSTNAME/repositories/git/REPNAME.git`

Host:  `HOSTNAME`

Rep path: `/repositories/git/REPNAME.git`

Protocol: `https`
Port: --

But when I click next, I get the following error:

```
Exception caught during execution of ls-remote command
```

I've googled and looked around, even saw some of the posts here on stackoverflow, however, I'm still unable to find the reason why this is happening.

EDIT: **SOLUTION**

Found the solution. Sorry for the bother. It seems that I had to turn off ssl verification:

```
git config --global http.sslverify "false"
```

Comment: Can you open the Git Repository view and try cloning the repo from there? Then importing your project from the Git Repository view?

Comment: @AndrewFinnell I have found the solution. Seems there's an error during ssl verification. Just had to turn it off in glob config. Somewhat ironic that I spent whole morning setting up git and getting angry over it nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Sorry for the bother. It seems that I had to turn off ssl verification:

```
git config --global http.sslverify "false"
```